# Unable to transfer files from handycam to PC

Tags: windows-7, usb, file-transfer, camera

I have a Windows 7 PC and Sony DCR-SR88 handycam. I need to transfer all my videos from the handycam to my PC.

When I try to connect to the PC via USB, it detects the handycam's drive on my PC and shows the used memory correctly, but when I open a folder, it says "folder is empty".

How I can copy the files?

I have tried following:

- Changed the USB cable.
- Changed the USB port.
- I can play the videos with the handycam, but the same files aren't visible in PC when connected in USB mode.

Comment: Are you sure you have videos on it? Try to play them back with the camera and let us know...

Comment: yes its there, i could play

Comment: What does the folder tree look like when you open it in Explorer? Are you sure you're looking in the right folder?

Comment: Isn't there some proprietary Sony software that you got as part of the package?

Answer (score 0):

That can possible that your data is hidden because of some virus or another reason.

Press `Alt` to reveal menu, then check `Show Hidden Files and Folder` from `Tools > Folder option > View` and uncheck `Hide Protected operating system files (Recommended)`.